# cx_Oracle: how do I get the ORA-xxxxx error number?

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

In a try/except block, how do I extract the Oracle error number?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
try:
   cursor.execute("select 1 / 0 from dual")
except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError, e:
   error, = e
   print "Code:", error.code
   print "Message:", error.message
```

This results in the following output:

```
Code: 1476
Message: ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero
```